# Rock paper scissors Vanilla JS - Does NOT reset classes when restart

Tags: javascript, html, reset

there are a lot of questiosn about this here but can't seen to find one for vanilla js..

Well here goes.
New class assigment : Rock paper scissors with vanilla js.

The game works in itself, the problem is when i want it to restart.
It seems to rung through all the new event listeners i put ? And i just don´t see why it does that, i only click on one of the buttons but it operates as if i clicked on them all in a row.

I'm sure the problem is in the lasts functions (the win, tie and lose screen). But i am at a loss as to what is the problem here.

Here is the git rep of the project :
[https://github.com/emma673r/rockpaperscissors][1]

and here is the code

```js
const gameField = document.getElementById(`gamefield`);
const player = document.getElementById(`player1`);
const computer = document.getElementById(`player2`);

const lose = document.getElementById(`lose`);
const win = document.getElementById(`win`);
const tie = document.getElementById(`tie`);

const rock = document.querySelector(`.rock`);
const paper = document.querySelector(`.paper`);
const scissors = document.querySelector(`.scissors`);

//rock = 0, paper = 1, scissors = 2
let compChoice;
compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

//rock = 0, paper = 1, scissors = 2
let userChoice;

// DOM load - send to titleScreen
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", titleScreen);

// titleScreen
function titleScreen() {
  console.log(`titleScreen`);

  tie.classList = "hidden";
  win.classList = "hidden";
  lose.classList = "hidden";

//   compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
//   console.log(`compChoice is : ${compChoice}`);

  // event listener rock btn click startGame
  rock.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsRock);
  // event listener paper btn click startGame
  paper.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsPaper);
  // event listener scissors btn click startGame
  scissors.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsScissors);
}

function shakeHandsRock() {
  console.log(`shakeHandsRock`);

    compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    console.log(`compChoice is : ${compChoice}`);

  player.classList.add("shake");
  computer.classList.add("shake");
  player.addEventListener("animationend", rockClicked);
}

function shakeHandsPaper() {
  console.log(`shakeHandsPaper`);

    compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    console.log(`compChoice is : ${compChoice}`);

  player.classList.add("shake");
  computer.classList.add("shake");
  player.addEventListener("animationend", paperClicked);
}

function shakeHandsScissors() {
  console.log(`shakeHandsScissors`);

    compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log(`compChoice is : ${compChoice}`);

  player.classList.add("shake");
  computer.classList.add("shake");
  player.addEventListener("animationend", scissorsClicked);
}

function rockClicked() {
  console.log(`rockClicked`);
  userChoice = 0;

  player.classList = "player rock";
  computer.classList = "player";

  player.classList.remove("shake");
  computer.classList.remove("shake");
  //   rock vs rock = tie
  if (userChoice == compChoice) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`rock`);

    tieScreen();
  }
  //   rock vs paper = player lose
  else if (compChoice == 1) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`paper`);

    loseScreen();
  }
  //   rock vs scissors = player win
  else if (compChoice == 2) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`scissors`);

    winScreen();
  }
}

function paperClicked() {
  console.log(`paperClicked`);
  userChoice = 1;

  player.classList = "player paper";
  computer.classList = "player";

  player.classList.remove("shake");
  computer.classList.remove("shake");

  //   paper vs rock = win
  if (compChoice == 0) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add("rock");

    winScreen();
  }
  //   paper vs paper = tie
  else if (compChoice == userChoice) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`paper`);

    tieScreen();
  }
  //   paper vs scissors = lose
  else if (compChoice == 2) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`scissors`);

    loseScreen();
  }
}

function scissorsClicked() {
  console.log(`scissorsClicked`);
  userChoice = 2;

  player.classList = "player scissors";
  computer.classList = "player";

  player.classList.remove("shake");
  computer.classList.remove("shake");

  //   scissors vs rock = lose
  if (compChoice == 0) {
    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`rock`);

    loseScreen();
  }
  //   scissors vs paper = win
  else if (compChoice == 1) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`paper`);

    winScreen();
  }
  //   scissors vs scissors = tie
  else if (compChoice == userChoice) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`scissors`);

    tieScreen();
  }
}

// tieScreen
function tieScreen() {
  console.log(`tieScreen`);

  // display block tie div
  tie.classList = "";
  win.classList = "hidden";
  lose.classList = "hidden";

  rock.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsRock);
  paper.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsPaper);
  scissors.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsScissors);
}

// winScreen
function winScreen() {
  console.log(`winScreen`);

  // display block win div
  win.classList = "";
  tie.classList = "hidden";
  lose.classList = "hidden";

  rock.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsRock);
  paper.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsPaper);
  scissors.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsScissors);
}
// loseScreen
function loseScreen() {
  console.log(`loseScreen`);

  // display block lose screen
  lose.classList = "";
  win.classList = "hidden";
  tie.classList = "hidden";

  rock.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsRock);
  paper.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsPaper);
  scissors.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsScissors);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #444059;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  color: #eee;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8vw;
}

#gamefield {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#player1 {
  --rot: 1;
}

#player2 {
  --rot: -1;
}

.player {
  transform: scale(var(--rot),1);
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url(hand_rock.png);
}

.player.rock {
  background-image: url(hand_rock.png);
}

.player.paper {
  background-image: url(hand_paper.png);
}

.player.scissors {
  background-image: url(hand_scissors.png);
}

.player.shake {
  background-image: url(hand_rock.png);
  transform-origin: left center;
  animation: shake 1.8s ease-in 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(-40deg);
  }
  24% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(5deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  48% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(-40deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(5deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(-40deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

#texts {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10vw;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#texts h1 {
  color: #ffde53;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px red, -4px -4px 1px red, 4px -4px 1px red, -4px 4px 1px red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 50vw;
}

#buttons.disabled button {
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(.75);
}

#buttons button {
  background-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  transition: filter .8s;
}

button.rock {
  background-image: url(button_rock.png);
}

button.paper {
  background-image: url(button_paper.png);
}

button.scissors {
  background-image: url(button_scissors.png);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>

    <div id="gamefield">
      <div id="player1" class="player"></div>
      <div id="player2" class="player"></div>
      <div id="texts">
        <div id="lose" class="hidden"><h1>You lose</h1></div>
        <div id="win" class="hidden"><h1>You win</h1></div>
        <div id="tie" class="hidden"><h1>It's a tie</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="buttons">
      <button class="rock"></button>
      <button class="paper"></button>
      <button class="scissors"></button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js
"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need the images, check the git rep, i don't seem to be allowed to post them here yet.

Thank you in advance, i've been stuck on this bug for a few hours now and even with a break i just dont see how i can fix it. I have tried many things but they don't work on the problem.
[1]: https://github.com/emma673r/rockpaperscissors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `JavaScript`, **`eventListeners` don't go away after they trigger the first time**. You have to manually remove an `eventListener` to stop it.

**The bug** was that your `rockClicked` was getting called *every* time the `player` finished its animation, once the `eventListener` had been set up. So I added a line to remove the `eventListener` when `rockClicked`, `paperClicked`, and `scissorsClicked` were called.

```js
const gameField = document.getElementById(`gamefield`);
const player = document.getElementById(`player1`);
const computer = document.getElementById(`player2`);

const lose = document.getElementById(`lose`);
const win = document.getElementById(`win`);
const tie = document.getElementById(`tie`);

const rock = document.querySelector(`.rock`);
const paper = document.querySelector(`.paper`);
const scissors = document.querySelector(`.scissors`);

// event listener rock btn click startGame
rock.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsRock);
// event listener paper btn click startGame
paper.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsPaper);
// event listener scissors btn click startGame
scissors.addEventListener("click", shakeHandsScissors);

//rock = 0, paper = 1, scissors = 2
let compChoice;
compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

//rock = 0, paper = 1, scissors = 2
let userChoice;

// DOM load - send to titleScreen
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", titleScreen);

// titleScreen
function titleScreen() {
  console.log(`titleScreen`);

  tie.classList = "hidden";
  win.classList = "hidden";
  lose.classList = "hidden";

//   compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
//   console.log(`compChoice is : ${compChoice}`);

}

function shakeHandsRock() {
  console.log(`shakeHandsRock`);

    compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    console.log(`compChoice is : ${compChoice}`);

  player.classList.add("shake");
  computer.classList.add("shake");
  player.addEventListener("animationend", rockClicked);
}

function shakeHandsPaper() {
  console.log(`shakeHandsPaper`);

    compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    console.log(`compChoice is : ${compChoice}`);

  player.classList.add("shake");
  computer.classList.add("shake");
  player.addEventListener("animationend", paperClicked);
}

function shakeHandsScissors() {
  console.log(`shakeHandsScissors`);

    compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log(`compChoice is : ${compChoice}`);

  player.classList.add("shake");
  computer.classList.add("shake");
  player.addEventListener("animationend", scissorsClicked);
}

function rockClicked() {
  player.removeEventListener("animationend", rockClicked);
  console.log(`rockClicked`);
  userChoice = 0;

  player.classList = "player rock";
  computer.classList = "player";

  player.classList.remove("shake");
  computer.classList.remove("shake");
  //   rock vs rock = tie
  if (userChoice == compChoice) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`rock`);

    tieScreen();
  }
  //   rock vs paper = player lose
  else if (compChoice == 1) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`paper`);

    loseScreen();
  }
  //   rock vs scissors = player win
  else if (compChoice == 2) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`scissors`);

    winScreen();
  }
}

function paperClicked() {
  player.removeEventListener("animationend", paperClicked);
  console.log(`paperClicked`);
  userChoice = 1;

  player.classList = "player paper";
  computer.classList = "player";

  player.classList.remove("shake");
  computer.classList.remove("shake");

  //   paper vs rock = win
  if (compChoice == 0) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add("rock");

    winScreen();
  }
  //   paper vs paper = tie
  else if (compChoice == userChoice) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`paper`);

    tieScreen();
  }
  //   paper vs scissors = lose
  else if (compChoice == 2) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`scissors`);

    loseScreen();
  }
}

function scissorsClicked() {
  player.removeEventListener("animationend", scissorsClicked);
  console.log(`scissorsClicked`);
  userChoice = 2;

  player.classList = "player scissors";
  computer.classList = "player";

  player.classList.remove("shake");
  computer.classList.remove("shake");

  //   scissors vs rock = lose
  if (compChoice == 0) {
    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`rock`);

    loseScreen();
  }
  //   scissors vs paper = win
  else if (compChoice == 1) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`paper`);

    winScreen();
  }
  //   scissors vs scissors = tie
  else if (compChoice == userChoice) {
    // shake animation

    // show hands pngs
    computer.classList.add(`scissors`);

    tieScreen();
  }
}

// tieScreen
function tieScreen() {
  console.log(`tieScreen`);

  // display block tie div
  tie.classList = "";
  win.classList = "hidden";
  lose.classList = "hidden";
}

// winScreen
function winScreen() {
  console.log(`winScreen`);

  // display block win div
  win.classList = "";
  tie.classList = "hidden";
  lose.classList = "hidden";
}
// loseScreen
function loseScreen() {
  console.log(`loseScreen`);

  // display block lose screen
  lose.classList = "";
  win.classList = "hidden";
  tie.classList = "hidden";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #444059;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  color: #eee;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8vw;
}

#gamefield {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#player1 {
  --rot: 1;
}

#player2 {
  --rot: -1;
}

.player {
  transform: scale(var(--rot),1);
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url(hand_rock.png);
}

.player.rock {
  background-image: url(hand_rock.png);
}

.player.paper {
  background-image: url(hand_paper.png);
}

.player.scissors {
  background-image: url(hand_scissors.png);
}

.player.shake {
  background-image: url(hand_rock.png);
  transform-origin: left center;
  animation: shake 1.8s ease-in 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(-40deg);
  }
  24% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(5deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  48% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(-40deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(5deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(-40deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(var(--rot),1) translateX(calc((var(--rot) - 1) * 50%)) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

#texts {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10vw;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#texts h1 {
  color: #ffde53;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px red, -4px -4px 1px red, 4px -4px 1px red, -4px 4px 1px red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 50vw;
}

#buttons.disabled button {
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(.75);
}

#buttons button {
  background-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  transition: filter .8s;
}

button.rock {
  background-image: url(button_rock.png);
}

button.paper {
  background-image: url(button_paper.png);
}

button.scissors {
  background-image: url(button_scissors.png);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>

    <div id="gamefield">
      <div id="player1" class="player"></div>
      <div id="player2" class="player"></div>
      <div id="texts">
        <div id="lose" class="hidden"><h1>You lose</h1></div>
        <div id="win" class="hidden"><h1>You win</h1></div>
        <div id="tie" class="hidden"><h1>It's a tie</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="buttons">
      <button class="rock"></button>
      <button class="paper"></button>
      <button class="scissors"></button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js
"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much, i got blind starring at it and wow, such an easy fix. Of course haha. Thank you so much